# how do i solve this Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/SecretKey

Tags: java

i also tried the below mentioned steps:

1. check maven version by mvn -version in cmd
2. check prerequisites such as gmconstant.js, application.prop, jboss-deploymnet_structure.xml,pom  file with others or follow the env setup document
3. check java version as 1.8.0_161 and ur maven version should be 3.6.2 or 3.6.3
4. if maven is not deploying try executing this command

   ```
   Call mvn -Dbuild.version=Local -Doutput.dir="C:\jboss-eap-7.0\standalone\deployments" clean install
   ```
5. try getting the entire project folder from others and check in your environment
6. if setting your environmental variables, then give SET PATH=C in command prompt as administrator
7. deleting the files unders .m2 folder /repository

   C:\Users\asophia.m2\repository
8. also added the below mention paths in environment variables

   ```
    C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_18\bin
    C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
   ```

   also set the path C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin in user variable

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the encryption jar in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext` or whatever jdk you are using and then register it as well.

Since you are using Oracle jdk, you probably need their jar (JCE).

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-downloads-java-plat-downloads.html#JCE-1_2_2-G-JS

Quoting the documentation:

> **Installing Providers**
>
> In order to be used, a cryptographic provider must first be installed, then registered either statically or dynamically.

> **Static Registration**
>
> The configuration file is located in the following location:
>
> Unix: /lib/security/java.security
>
> Windows: \lib\security\java.security

You can check the documentation for a well detailed explanation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html